# matlab to c++: Cannot open include file: 'mclmcrrt.h': No such file or directory

Tags: matlab-deployment

We tried to complie the m file to c++ file by matlab complier. We had the file bulit but we got the error msg as follow.

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mclmcrrt.h': No such file or directory

Do you have any ideas about the error msg? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Ying

Answer (score 2):

This error message is caused because you need MCR dlls.
You should locate the h file in   **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\extern\include\"**
and add it to your include path in C.

Check out the manual of Matlab compiler.